# How should I get a long type date from a database bound to a text view as a properly formatted date?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am storing my date as milliseconds to my database. Later on, I am trying to load that from the database and with SimpleCursorAdapter load it on a text view. However, every time I call it I get the milliseconds back as String, so when I bind it on a text view, instead of the proper format I see the milliseconds.

The variables:

```java
    public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COL_CONTENT = "content";
    public static final String COL_IMPORTANT = "important";

    private static final int INDEX_ID = 0;
    public static final int INDEX_DATE = INDEX_ID + 1;
    public static final int INDEX_CONTENT = INDEX_ID + 2;
    public static final int INDEX_IMPORTANT = INDEX_ID+ 3;
```

Create function in Database adapter:

```java
    public void createEvent(long day, String name, boolean important) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_DATE, day);
        values.put(COL_CONTENT, name);
        values.put(COL_IMPORTANT, important ? 1 : 0);
        mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
```

The table creation query:

```java
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                    COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, " +
                    COL_DATE + " INTEGER, " +
                    COL_CONTENT + " TEXT, " +
                    COL_IMPORTANT + " INTEGER );";
```

My activities call:

```java
        mDbAdapter = new EventsDbAdapter(this);
        mDbAdapter.open();
        Cursor cursor = mDbAdapter.fetchAllEvents();
        String[] from = new String[] {EventsDbAdapter.COL_DATE, EventsDbAdapter.COL_CONTENT};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.event_list_row_dayTextView, R.id.event_list_row_dataTextView};
        mCursorAdapter = new EventsSimpleCursorAdapter(
                CalendarActivity.this,
                R.layout.event_feed_item_row,
                cursor,
                from,
                to,
                0);
        mListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
```

SimpleCursorAdapter class code:

```java
    public EventsSimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from,
                                      int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        if ( holder == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.colImp = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(EventsDbAdapter.COL_IMPORTANT);
            holder.listTab = view.findViewById(R.id.event_list_row_cardLayout);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        if(cursor.getInt(holder.colImp) > 0) {
            holder.listTab.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_event_dark_color));
        } else {
            holder.listTab.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_event_primary_color));
        }
    }
```

The issue is with the From variable, as the `EventsDbAdapter.COL_DATE`returns as a string and that String holds the milliseconds. I tried formatting it by using `Long.parse(EventsDbAdapter.COL_DATE)` and then pass it to this function:

```java
    public static String getDateFormated(long milliSeconds)
    {
        String dateFormat = "dd";
        // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
        android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter = new android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

        // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

But that does not work as the parse needs to catch the exception.

So my expected results would be to call to the database, get the milliseconds, convert them to a date format ("DD") and bind it to a text view.

The result I have now:

[image]

Should be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could change the **fetchAllEvents** method to return a Cursor that includes the date formatted as required, as an additional column *(you therefore don't need to convert/format anything the value you want is provided directly)*.

This could be based upon using `strftime('%d'," + COL_DATE + " / 1000,'unixepoch')`. This :-

1. takes the value in the COL_DATE and divides it by 1000 to drop the milliseconds,
2. modifies the value to be considered as a unix time, rather than a julian day.
3. formats the value DD format using the **%d** formatter.

Your **fecthAllEvents** method could be something like :-

```
public Cursor fetchAllEvents() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{"*","strftime('%d'," + COL_DATE + " / 1000,'unixepoch') AS date_as_DD"}; //<<<<<<<<<< this gets the day of the month DD from the timestamp
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Then column **date_as_DD** could be retrieved as a string from the Cursor by the adapter.

- ***Note the above code is in-principle code. It has not been syntax checked or run and may therefore contain some errors.***
- Note if you wanted single digits for days under 10 then you could modify the above to use `CAST(strftime('%d',date/1000,'unixepoch') AS INTEGER) AS date_as_DD` (i.e. force an INTEGER type rather than a TEXT type).

## Testing

The above is based upon the following test code :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date INTEGER, content TEXT, important INTEGER);
-- add some data with unix dates with milliseconds (i.e. * 1000)
INSERT INTO mytable (date,content,important) VALUES(strftime('%s','now') * 1000,'blah',0);
INSERT INTO mytable (date,content,important) VALUES(strftime('%s','now','-1 Day') * 1000,'blah',0);
INSERT INTO mytable (date,content,important) VALUES(strftime('%s','now','-7 Day') * 1000,'blah',0);
INSERT INTO mytable (date,content,important) VALUES(strftime('%s','now','-10 Day') * 1000,'blah',0);
INSERT INTO mytable (date,content,important) VALUES(strftime('%s','now','-20 Day') * 1000,'blah',0);
INSERT INTO mytable (date,content,important) VALUES(strftime('%s','now','-1 Month') * 1000,'blah',0);
SELECT *, datetime(date/1000,'unixepoch') AS fulldate, strftime('%d',date/1000,'unixepoch') AS date_as_DD FROM mytable;
```

Which results in :-

[image]

- The **fulldate** column shows the complete date and time (and would not be needed)
- The **date_as_DD** is the new column that would be available.
- You may want to create a constant for the column name e.g. `DERIVED_COL_DATEASDD = "date_as_DD";` to be used throughout.

e.g.

```
String[] from = new String[] {EventsDbAdapter.COL_DATE, EventsDbAdapter.COL_CONTENT};
```

could be changed to :-

```
String[] from = new String[] {"date_as_DD", EventsDbAdapter.COL_CONTENT};
```

or, if the constant **DERIVED_COL_DATEASDD** is used, to :-

```
String[] from = new String[] {EventsDbAdapter.DERIVED_COL_DATEASDD, EventsDbAdapter.COL_CONTENT};
```

You may want to have a look at [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks! Will look into the Date and Time functions